# All purpose, high end Laptop/Ultrabook

Tags: laptop, high-end

I am looking for an ultrabook or a lightweight laptop to replace my old Lenovo.

The main applications I use are development (Mainly in number crunching and Machine Learning, for the intensive applications), the Adobe suite (especially premiere pro, after effects and photoshop), and a few old games. The rest is mostly a matter of taking notes and web browsing. I operate a dualboot to optimize all of those tasks.

My minimum requirements are 12Gb of RAM, a small GPU, and enough memory to be comfortable, with a SSD being a plus. I'm more of an AMD fan as far as CPUs are concerned but I'm sadly unable to find any laptop coming with Ryzen CPUs.

Oh, and as I intend to carry it around quite a lot, 13-14" screens are almost mandatory.

I don't want to spend over 1,200$ - except maybe for an outstanding config.

I came across the Asus UX410UF-GV049T, which has an 8th gen Intel Core i7, a 1 Tb HDD, a 256 Gb SSD, 16 Gb of RAM and a Nvidia GeForce MX 130 2G, with a sale making it worth just 1,000$ ; should I go for it or do you have a better option to propose ? I intend on keeping it at least 4-5 years si I'd like to have a second opinion :)

Thank you for your time,

Frost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for price, an [HP EliteBook 725 G3](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100006740%20600136700&IsNodeId=1&Description=HP%20EliteBook%20725%20G3&name=Laptops%20%2f%20Notebooks&Order=PRICE&Pagesize=60&isdeptsrh=1) would be your best bet, with   a 12.5" HD screen, and prices starting at $649 right now.

But, in fact, for only $899, you can get the [Lenovo ThinkPad E485](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=9SIA7AB7ZH6307) with a 14" HD screen, and a Ryzen (yes!) processor. ($799 if you're willing to drop the SSD requirement.)  Notice that SSD size upgrades are *very* cheap for this model; I'd pay the $100 to upgrade to the 512GB SSD if I were buying this.

Of course, there are *many* more choices.  Many.

Comment: Alright, I've checked averything, thank you ! I still think I'm gonna go for the zenbook, but I could check similar configurations and that's very cool, thanks :)

Comment: No, thank *you* for coming back to let us know.  Many people post on here, get their answer, and we never hear from them again so much as to know whether they've even read our answer.

Comment: Heads up, your Amazon link shows the item as unavailable. Also, I've found Amazon to be an adequately reliable purveyor to the likes of Newegg. They're good places to cut down on price as I'm sure you know.

Comment: @BennettYeo It looks like `Frost` bought the only available unit at that price.  :)